# What happens to shared data when the app is uninstall

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, uninstallation

I want to share the data between two android apps :

One way is use external storage :
    - SD card or Internally provided storage to store the public files and share across the applications

Second way is use ContentProvider (used for large structured storage) :
I was referening to the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9602828 ,

My question is :

Can we access shared preference file from another application context ?

and can we store the shared preferences to external storage ?

Comment: Shared preferences can be private or shared, so **yes** I'm guessing you can access the file from another application if it is shared. [Refer here for more info](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: @YourJavaMinion thanks, but I am more interested into - can we store the shared preferences to external storage ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access shared preference through following code if your preference is WORLD_READABLE-

```
Context mContext = createPackageContext("com.example.yourpackage", 
Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
SharedPreferences sharedPreference = mContext.getSharedPreferences 
("Preference_Name", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Comment: thanks, but I am more interested into - can we store the shared preferences to external storage ?

Comment: You can write file from sharedPreference content into sdcard but there is no method provided by SharedPreference to store it externally

Comment: To store it in file, you can get example here-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864462/how-can-i-backup-sharedpreferences-to-sd-card