# Have some hard-coded value in RoomDatabase that won't disappear after uninstalling

Tags: java, android, android-room

building an Android App using Room DB. I've uninstalled the app various times but always seem to get the same entry as i re-install it.

I can't seem to reach the onCreate part of the RoomDatabase.Callback as I'm trying to add some dummy entries and log some info to the logs.

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ContactsAdapter contactsAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ContactsAppDatabase contactsAppDatabase;
    private static final String TAG="MainActivityTag";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" Contacts Manager ");

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_contacts);
        contactsAppDatabase= Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),ContactsAppDatabase.class,"ContactDB")
                .addCallback(callback)
                .build();



        new GetAllContactsAsyncTask().execute();

        contactsAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(this, contactArrayList, MainActivity.this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addAndEditContacts(false, null, -1);
            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void addAndEditContacts(final boolean isUpdate, final Contact contact, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.layout_add_contact, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(view);

        TextView contactTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.new_contact_title);
        final EditText newContact = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        final EditText contactEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.email);

        contactTitle.setText(!isUpdate ? "Add New Contact" : "Edit Contact");

        if (isUpdate && contact != null) {
            newContact.setText(contact.getName());
            contactEmail.setText(contact.getEmail());
        }

        alertDialogBuilderUserInput
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(isUpdate ? "Update" : "Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Delete",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {

                                if (isUpdate) {

                                    deleteContact(contact, position);
                                } else {

                                    dialogBox.cancel();

                                }

                            }
                        });


        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newContact.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter contact name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }


                if (isUpdate && contact != null) {

                    updateContact(newContact.getText().toString(), contactEmail.getText().toString(), position);
                } else {

                    createContact(newContact.getText().toString(), contactEmail.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void deleteContact(Contact contact, int position) {

        contactArrayList.remove(position);

        new DeleteContactAsyncTask().execute(contact);

    }

    private void updateContact(String name, String email, int position) {

        Contact contact = contactArrayList.get(position);

        contact.setName(name);
        contact.setEmail(email);



        new UpdateContactAsyncTask().execute(contact);

        contactArrayList.set(position, contact);




    }

    private void createContact(String name, String email) {

        new CreateContactAsyncTask().execute(new Contact(0,name,email));

    }

    private class GetAllContactsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            contactArrayList.addAll(contactsAppDatabase.getContactDAO().getContacts());
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


    private class CreateContactAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Contact,Void,Void>{



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Contact... contacts) {

            long id = contactsAppDatabase.getContactDAO().addContact(contacts[0]);


            Contact contact = contactsAppDatabase.getContactDAO().getContact(id);

            if (contact != null) {

                contactArrayList.add(0, contact);


            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class UpdateContactAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Contact,Void,Void>{


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Contact... contacts) {

            contactsAppDatabase.getContactDAO().updateContact(contacts[0]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class DeleteContactAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Contact,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Contact... contacts) {

            contactsAppDatabase.getContactDAO().deleteContact(contacts[0]);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    RoomDatabase.Callback callback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," On Create Called ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, " on create invoked ");

            createContact("name 1","email 1");
            createContact("name 2","email 2");
            createContact("name 3","email 3");


        }


        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);

            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," On Create Called ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(TAG, " on open invoked ");

        }

    };

}
```

I've added write/ read external storage in the manifest unsure if thats important.

Things is onOpen gets invoked from within the callback so it seems a little weird.

[github repo](https://github.com/BenMohammad/ContactManager)

when I install the app onanother device it works fine. obviously on the other (the first) device I still get the error even after deleting and reinstalling the app.

Please help.

Comment: I think it'll help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915039/database-wont-remove-when-uninstall-the-android-application

Comment: Thank you Maya works great!!