# Android application delete - SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, sharedpreferences

When i delete my application from my Android phone and reinstall the app again via Android Studio the application still has all the data from the old install.

I use SQLite database for data storage and i use the Shared Preference for some basic information.

How do you guys make sure the db is cleared when the app is deleted?

Would like to hear your insights!

Comment: Does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9602828/3159267

Comment: @RajanKali a little bit, why is it that when i deleted the app myself the database was not deleted? Could this be because i was 'to quick'?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app from your device or run:

```
adb uninstall <your_app_id>
```

from the terminal to uninstall the app.

This will remove the SQLite database and SharedPreferences.

Comment: I understand that but i need to fix this for users that uninstall and reinstall via playstore.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I misunderstood your question.